# How can I display 64 bit double number using VBScript on 32 Bit OS?

Tags: vbscript, double

I have a device that contains 64 bit number (Double) parameters. I can read its Double parameters using Modbus protocol in two parts. So I split the 64 bit number to two 32 bit numbers using bitwise operation.

Example: `2289225.841082` (decimal) = `41417724-EBA8953E` (hex)

You can check and test Hex conversation in the following site: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/ Copy `41417724EBA8953E` and paste in "Value to analyze" edit-box in above site and press enter.

But after transferring the two 32 bit integers I can *not* merge it to original 64 bit number. I tried to use the `CDbl` and `FormatNumber` functions in VBScript, but it fails!

```vbs
Dim nL, nH, fL, fH, f64 
nL = 1094809380 ' 4141 7724
nH = 3953694014 ' EBA8 953E
fL = CDbl($nL)
fH = CDbl($nH)
f64 = CDbl((fH * CDbl(2 ^ 32)) + CDbl(fL))
$strNum64 = FormatNumber( f64, 2)
```

So, how can I display a 64 bit number using VBScript on a 32 bit OS?

Answer (score 1):

The "simple" answer to this, assuming pure VBScript, was to write a bignum add and multiply and then calculate the answer that way.

Using code from [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Long_Multiplication#Liberty_BASIC), I've created the following VeryLargeInteger class and a Hex64 function which says that 4702170486407730494 is the 64 bit decimal equivalent of 0x41417724EBA8953E

```
Option Explicit
Class VeryLongInteger
    'http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Long_Multiplication#Liberty_BASIC
    Public Function MULTIPLY(Str_A, Str_B)
        Dim signA, signB, sResult, Str_Shift, i, d, Str_T
        signA = 1
        If Left(Str_A,1) = "-" Then 
            Str_A = Mid(Str_A,2)
            signA = -1
        End If
        signB = 1
        If Left(Str_B,1) = "-" Then 
            Str_B = Mid(Str_B,2)
            signB = -1
        End If
        sResult = vbNullString
        Str_T = vbNullString
        Str_shift = vbNullString
        For i = Len(Str_A) To 1 Step -1
            d = CInt(Mid(Str_A,i,1))
            Str_T = MULTBYDIGIT(Str_B, d)
            sResult = ADD(sResult, Str_T & Str_shift)
            Str_shift = Str_shift & "0"
            'print d, Str_T, sResult 
        Next
        If signA * signB < 0 Then sResult = "-" + sResult
        'print sResult
        MULTIPLY = sResult
    End Function

    Private Function MULTBYDIGIT(Str_A, d)
        Dim sResult, carry, i, a, c
        'multiply Str_A by digit d
        sResult = vbNullString
        carry = 0
        For i = Len(Str_A) To 1 Step -1
            a = CInt(Mid(Str_A,i,1))
            c = a * d + carry
            carry = c \ 10
            c = c Mod 10
            'print a, c
            sResult = CStr(c) & sResult 
        Next
        If carry > 0 Then sResult = CStr(carry) & sResult
        'print sResult
        MULTBYDIGIT = sResult
    End Function

    Public Function ADD(Str_A, Str_B)
        Dim L, sResult, carry, i, a, b, c
        'add Str_A + Str_B, for now only positive
        l = MAX(Len(Str_A), Len(Str_B))
        Str_A=PAD(Str_A,l)
        Str_B=PAD(Str_B,l)
        sResult = vbNullString 'result
        carry = 0
        For i = l To 1 Step -1
            a = CInt(Mid(Str_A,i,1))
            b = CInt(Mid(Str_B,i,1))
            c = a + b + carry
            carry = Int(c/10)
            c = c Mod 10
            'print a, b, c
            sResult = CStr(c) & sResult
        Next
        If carry>0 Then sResult = CStr(carry) & sResult
        'print sResult
        ADD = sResult
    End Function

    Private Function Max(a,b)
        If a > b Then
            Max = a
        Else
            Max = b
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function pad(a,n)  'pad from right with 0 to length n
        Dim sResult
        sResult = a
        While Len(sResult) < n
            sResult = "0" & sResult
        Wend
        pad = sResult
    End Function
End Class

Function Hex64(sHex)
    Dim VLI
    Set VLI = New VeryLongInteger

    Dim Sixteen(16)
    Sixteen(0) = "1"
    Sixteen(1) = "16"
    Sixteen(2) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(1),"16")
    Sixteen(3) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(2),"16")
    Sixteen(4) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(3),"16")
    Sixteen(5) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(4),"16")
    Sixteen(6) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(5),"16")
    Sixteen(7) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(6),"16")
    Sixteen(8) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(7),"16")
    Sixteen(9) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(8),"16")
    Sixteen(10) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(9),"16")
    Sixteen(11) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(10),"16")
    Sixteen(12) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(11),"16")
    Sixteen(13) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(12),"16")
    Sixteen(14) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(13),"16")
    Sixteen(15) = VLI.MULTIPLY(Sixteen(14),"16")

    Dim theAnswer, i, theDigit, theMultiplier, thePower, aPower
    theAnswer = "0"
    aPower = 0
    For i = Len(sHex) To 1 Step -1
        theDigit = UCase(Mid(sHex,i,1))
        theMultiplier = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF",theDigit)-1
        thePower = Sixteen(aPower)
        thePower = VLI.MULTIPLY(CStr(theMultiplier),thePower)
        theAnswer = VLI.ADD(theAnswer,thePower )
        aPower = aPower + 1
    Next
    Hex64 = theAnswer
End Function

WScript.Echo Hex64("41417724EBA8953E")
```

I'd like to say "enjoy" but it's been more than six months since the original posting, so you've likely found another solution. All the same, it was fun.

**LATER**

The other way to do the Hex64, if you want to avoid the precalculation of the powers of 16 is:

```
Function Hex64b(sHex)
    Dim VLI
    Set VLI = New VeryLongInteger       
    Dim theAnswer, i, theDigit, theMultiplier, thePower, aPower
    theAnswer = "0"
    thePower = "1"
    For i = Len(sHex) To 1 Step -1
        theDigit = UCase(Mid(sHex,i,1))
        theMultiplier = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF",theDigit)-1
        theAnswer = VLI.ADD(theAnswer,VLI.MULTIPLY(thePower,theMultiplier))
        thePower = VLI.MULTIPLY(thePower,"16")
    Next
    Hex64b = theAnswer
End Function
```